How to prevent gdb step into STL implementation?
I'm debugging some C++ code in CLion with GDB.
I've noticed that when I step on a line containing stl function call and click 'step into' CLion will firstly show the stl implementation which I don't need at all.
For example:
vector<Detection> a;
a.push_back(GetDetection());

When current step is on a.push_back(GetDetection());, if I click step into on CLion's debug pannel, it will firstly step into the implementation of push_back (i.e. show me stl_vector.h), then I need to click step out and finally I see how GetDetection implements, which is very annoying.
Is there any method to prevent step into stl implementations?
Note that do NOT skip stl when STEP OVER (I've seen some answers hint using skip -gfi 'std::.*', but it just ignore all breakpoints on stl calls), just prevent STEP INTO stl implementations.

Step over those lines instead. If you want to see the GetDetection constructor place a breakpoint on that.

Near duplicate: How to disable stepping in C++ template while walking thru code using GDB? Skip is the best you'll get unless someone's done some really neat work in the last couple years.

In this example, I would expect that it first steps into GetDetection(), am I missing something?

@ssbssa No, it first steps into push_back, not GetDetection.

That's not happening for me, and it also doesn't make any sense (except maybe if compiled with optimization). Maybe you could show a small reproducer, compile commands, plus gdb session.
